# Where does Firefox store bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Does anyone know where Firefox is keeping the details about the bookmarks? For example, when I'm browsing the net and I see an interesting page but I don't have time to read it in that moment, I drag&drop it in bookmarks toolbar.

How does Firefox know which those pages are? I'm not talking about right_click->properties. I wish to know where on my HDD those links are kept.

TY

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, Firefox stores your bookmarks in a file called "**places.sqlite**" in the profile folder. The full path for that file is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\places.sqlite
```

If you double click on "bookmarks.html" which UK has pointed, you cannot see your recorded bookmarks in it. You can use `Bookmarks -> Organize Bookmarks -> Import and Backup` to export your bookmarks into **json** or **html** formats.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't know they changed this. Funny thing is since I have an old installation of windows and FF I still have a bunch of bookmarks in bookmarks.html file so I never realized that new ones are not there.

Comment: "import your bookmarks into json or html formats" Don't you mean export into? Or import from?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Corrected!

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong , Firefox stores it in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>\bookmarks.html
```

Comment: Just open bookmarks.html (7 KB) and you won't see your recorded bookmarks in it. Please see my answer below.