# Firefox migration

Tags: firefox, firefox-3.6

My computer had a problem and I lost my system drive.

I have got my old Firefox 3 user files with a lot of bookmarks in.

but I cannot seem to find information for putting these bookmmrks into Firefox 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue : Firefox makes backup bookmark files in the json format located in your user folder appdata/roaming/mozilla/firefox/profiles//bookmarkbackups

the boomarks.html file only kept the default firefox boomarks

Comment: Yakou:  That's very good information, thanks!  It seems that Firefox has changed over time with regards to what it keeps in that bookmarks.html file.

Answer (score 2):

The bookmarks are stored in a file called "bookmarks.html" and you should be able to just import them with the Bookmark Management options in Firefox 4 -- when managing your bookmarks, look for an "Import" option and choose "from file" then navigate to your old Firefox 3 user files and select "bookmarks.html."

Comment: any luck on your openid issues @Randolf?

Comment: Related: [Where does Firefox store bookmarks?](http://superuser.com/questions/71144/where-does-firefox-store-bookmarks)

Comment: @studiohack:  They haven't responded to my questions about why the URI they provide in the eMail doesn't work (I know how to deal with multi-line URIs), and I'm starting to wonder if OpenID might be one of those "set it up and forget about it" systems.  Thanks for following up!  (It sure would be nice to just verify my account here with my eMail address.)

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: again, anything **I** can do, just let me know! we're here to help!

Comment: @studiohack:  Anything?  >B-)  Get SuperUser.com to add a validation mechanism that uses regular eMail addresses.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson **I** can't do that, as that is a developer-only thing...was referring to linking accounts and such...ah well

Comment: @studiohack:  Thanks, I really appreciate your help with this while I wait for the folks at OpenID.org to respond to my eMails.  Of course, if they don't respond I'll just have to dump them and find something else that is actually run by real people.

Comment: @RandolfRichardson hope it works out!