# Does Firefox store bookmarks as individual files anywhere?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, bookmarks

Many years ago in the time of Windows XP, I remember that Internet Explorer had a "Favourites" folder containing each bookmark as a standalone file. This enabled easy drag-and-drop operations on bookmarks, as well as other simple management techniques.

Does Firefox store bookmarks individually this way, and if so, where does it store them? I'm aware of `places.sqlite`, but that's one large file, and not really human-readable.

(I know [Where does Firefox store bookmarks?](https://superuser.com/questions/71144/where-does-firefox-store-bookmarks) exists, but that's not a duplicate. That's just asking about the location of bookmarks generally, not whether standalone individual files exist.)

Comment: @JonathanGarber - Not a duplicate. Have seen that question before and it didn't answer mine. Edit : I was afraid this was going to happen.. looks like I won't find my answer here.

Comment: Mmph. Fair enough. I'm not sure whether it's possible to enable such a thing without an export, but for sure it doesn't exist by default.

Comment: @JonathanGarber Is it possible, please, for you to remove the Link to another question ? As it may confuse viewers that the question actually is about the same thing, and shy them away from answering ? Thank you.

Comment: I'll do that. You might edit your question to make it explicitly clear that you're asking about a human-readable bookmarks file, rather than the location of the bookmarks file generally. (That was the source of my confusion in the first place.) Actually, I'll take a crack at it myself.

Comment: @JonathanGarber - Thank you very much. Clearly, I would have asked the question in a proper way if I knew how to express it like you did.

Comment: It is a duplicate, IMO.  You're asking if they're stored in separate files, and where those would be. The answer is in the duplicate: "they are stored in a single SQLite file, in XYZ location".  So, I'm not sure why you don't feel that answers "Are they stored in separate files?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an easy way to access the profile folder [since Firefox version 13](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Troubleshooting_Information_page).

Just enter `about:support` in your address bar. This will open a page for troubleshooting. It contains a button to open the profile folder in the file manager of your Operating System.

The actual bookmarks are not stored as separate files like in Internet Explorer. They are stored as a SQLite database (`places.sqlite`) which is not accessible by normal means. There is also a `bookmarkbackups/` subdirectory which contains daily backups of your bookmarks which can be [re-imported](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them) into a Firefox installation.

If you press `CTRL+SHIFT+B` you open the bookmarks manager which is similar to your way of accessing IE's favorites. You can also export bookmarks into an HTML file and use that file as your default homepage.

More technical information about Firefox bookmarks can be found in the Mozilla Knowledgebase: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Bookmarks

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there basically is no such option to navigate and use bookmarks as favourites were (are?) used in IE ? Can you expand your answer to tell more about exporting bookmarks into an HTML file ? I tried to do is at he link said, and I got one big long horrible looking html text that wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: You can use the bookmarks library to nagivate your bookmarks in an explorer-like way. The HTML file isn't really helpful, I grant you that. But I definitely prefer the bookmarks library over the favorite functionality in Internet Explorer. That's just a personal preference, however.